# Javascript unexpected return value with specific indentation

Tags: javascript

I got an unexpected return value "undefined" from function 'fnExample1' if I indent code like this :

```
function fnExample1() {
  return
  1;
}
```

I have made this simple example : [Example jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u98q19tc/3/)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

write `return` and `1` in one line

```
function fnExample1() {
  return 1;
}
```

The reason why your code returns undefined is javascript's "[semicolon insertion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis#Semicolon_insertion)", where a semicolon is inserted after `return`, and `1` is considered another statement (which is not executed)